# What Maven multi module project structure for Subversion, Hudson, GWT Google Plugin, M2Eclipse?

Tags: svn, gwt, hudson, m2eclipse

I setup a flat Maven project layout with a relative path from parent to modules in the POM files. This builds fine in Maven and the Google Plugin for Eclipse runs the GWT web application. But then I couldn't find a clear explanation for configuring Hudson to find the modules from the parent. Also, a developer objected to each module having its own trunk/branch/tags Subversion layout.

I re-factored, putting modules under the parent. M2Eclipse created a project for each module. But this is confusing; the parent project also has the module code. They don't seem to be links, so the same code is in two places and editing in one place doesn't change it in the other.

Adding the parent with modules to Subversion and then checking it in turns the module projects into mere folders; the Google Plugin can't find a web application to run but it does build in Maven.

I tried checking out the GWT module as a project but running as a web application fails because it's in a different directory.

So, I am trying to put make these things work together in a standard-ish way. How do I configure Hudson for a flat layout Maven multi module project? Or. How do I use a nested layout that allows me to use the GWT Google Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Your question really has to many aspects, but in terms of Hudson integration I would suggest to just figure out how to build the project with Maven on the command line first. Then creating a build on Hudson will be easy by just adding the build steps you do on the command line as separate Maven 3 steps in a freestyle project.